How to make an infinite repeating projection in QGIS
I'm using the EPSG:3857 projection in QGIS. And I use a raster relief layer and several vector layers. Is it possible to make the map not interrupt at 180 degrees, but continue?


No, you've already drawn that data on the otherside of the map drawing it again would be a problem

And even no custom projection will help?

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30902. Not possible at the moment, otherwise, QGIS issue would be closed whereas it remains opened.
There is also a similar question where there was never an answer QGIS to have infinite map canvas in East-West direction
